# import .csv file to excel with space between lines

Tags: excel, import-from-excel, vba

i am trying to import a .CSV file(imported from email outlook) to excel sheet, .CSV file contains 6 lines, line number 5 is empty, under this code excel import just the first 4 lines and ignore Line 6, error is "Subscript is put of range" how can i solve this. thanks in advance 
    Sub OpenOneFile()

```
Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = "D:\Excel\Learning Excel VBA\Outlook VBA\Email1.csv"
Open FilePath For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, linefromfile
        Lineitems = Split(linefromfile, ":")

        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = Lineitems(0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = Lineitems(1)

        row_number = row_number + 1

    Loop
Close #1
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `Split` of an empty line, you can not reference `Lineitems (0)` because there are no values.
Try this:

```
Sub OpenOneFile()
Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = "D:\Excel\Learning Excel VBA\Outlook VBA\Email1.csv"

Open FilePath For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, linefromfile
    If linefromfile <> "" Then
        Lineitems = Split(linefromfile, ":")

        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = Lineitems(0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = Lineitems(1)

        row_number = row_number + 1
    End If
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, but after macro run still have same error "Subscript is out of range" could it be from DO Loop?